Remove permissions .DUMP and "Activity (com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity)"
I developed a React Native app with Expo for a payment machine.
During the homologation process, I was asked to remove certain permissions.
I managed to remove basic permissions like .INTERNET and .VIBRATE using tools:node="remove". However, I now need to remove .DUMP and the activity com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity, and they are not being removed with the same method. I haven't found any information on how to remove these specific permissions.
How can I remove these specific permissions?
I have already tried using blockedPermission in app.json and directly adding tools:node="remove" in the AndroidManifest.
I need my final APK to not have .DUMP and com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity enabled.

Please provide a [mcve] showing what you are trying.

@CommonsWare , i dont know how to do this minimal reproducible examble in this scenary

You wrote "I have already tried using blockedPermission in app.json and directly adding tools:node="remove" in the AndroidManifest.". So, you could edit your question and post the contents of those two files (app.json, AndroidManifest.xml).
